# Как узнать цвет конкретного пикселя в JFrame?

Tags: java, jframe

Нужно узнать цвет отдельного пикселя в jframe, задав x и y.

Answer (score 0):

Тыркнуть в них роботом? Мне кажется этот путь странным, но он довольно простой. Если нужно красить, то есть у BufferedImage метод для покраски.

[ссылка на стек с роботом 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217148/get-pixel-color-on-screen-java)

[ссылка на стек с роботом 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246988/cannot-get-colour-of-pixel-on-screen)

[Еще одна ссылка, но через графикс](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307962/how-to-get-the-color-of-a-point-in-a-jpanel)